# Diagnosing power supply failures

Tags: troubleshooting, power-supply

I had my power supply experience a catastrophic failure (distinctive crack and electrical discharge noise, electrical burning smell) not long ago. It had been in use for over two years before failing (all components are roughly that age except the mobo; that was replaced with an RMA about 6 months ago after a failure).

Assuming it was just a PSU failure, after getting and installing a replacement, I went about stress testing to ensure the new PSU worked. It did - for about an hour. The same failure experience - I managed to see visible sparking from within the PSU this time. I was monitoring my internal temperatures and they seemed appropriate.

I made the mistake of using the same power cable rather than the new cable for the PSU, but in other testing that cable seems to be alright. I did take a 400W+ PSU and hook up the motherboard, CPU, and a hard drive and let it run for a few minutes - no failure there, but it's a significantly fewer number of components, and no load.

What other actions can I take to debug the potential issue with my build?

Edit:

**Build**

- [GIGABYTE Ultra Durable VGA Series GV-R685OC-1GD Radeon HD 6850 1GB 256-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 2.1 x16](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125353)
- [Crucial RealSSD C300 CTFDDAC064MAG-1G1CCA 2.5" 64GB SATA III MLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148361)
- [ASUS M4A87TD/USB3 AM3 AMD 870 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131651)
- [Sunbeam PSU-H680-REV-US 680W ATX 12V 2.0 Power Supply - OEM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817709027)
- [G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 4GB (2 x 2GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model F3-12800CL9D-4GBRL](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231277)
- [Western Digital WD Black WD5002AALX 500GB 7200 RPM 32MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136795)
- [AMD Phenom II X4 965 Black Edition Deneb 3.4GHz Socket AM3 125W Quad-Core Processor HDZ965FBGMBOX](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103727)
- [Rosewill CHALLENGER Black Gaming ATX Mid Tower Computer Case, comes with Three Fans-1x Front Blue LED 120mm Fan, 1x Top 140mm ...](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811147153)
- [ASUS PCE-N13 PCI Express 150/300Mbps Transfer/Receive Rate Wireless Adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320048)
- [ASUS DRW-24B1ST/BLK/B/AS Black SATA 24X DVD Burner - Bulk - OEM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827135204)

The RAM has since changed to 8GB of Ripjaws DDR3, but I am unsure of the model.

Comment: You should post your build.

Comment: @pnuts - Someone's cracked the PSU and it's more than just a fuse, there were some very damaged components.

Comment: @MDMoore313 Added.

Comment: Since its cracked open - might help to see what parts are damaged - are they ICs or capasitors? A bad cable and a power spike COULD do this

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how big your replacement PSU was, but from experience and your build I have to say that

> 1) It's likely the power supply just died, they do that occasionally (die prematurely, that is)
>
> 2)Your video card is a tremendous power drain. It requires a 500w power supply just to function. While it likely may not draw the entire 500w, that is something to keep an eye on. If it does draw the entire 500, you want to take the time to calculate the rest of your wattage requirements from your build and see if 680 is sufficient. ***Operating a power supply close to it's max will also shorten its lifespan***.

I or you will probably never know what truly happened to your beloved power supply, but at least know a possible reason, and can take preventative measures in the future.

Comment: The fact that both power supplies died the same way means I doubt the first possibility, and the second is possible but unlikely - that 500W is a recommeded PSU size, not what the card actually pulls. It pulls more like 230W - see http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/graphics/2010/10/22/ati-radeon-hd-6850-review/9.

Comment: That's still pretty intense for a video card, when you factor in that your processor drains 125W peak without any other peripherals that's already 70% of your power supplies max. That may not sound like a lot, but that doesn't include the actual *motherboard*, hard drives, dvd burner, and any usb devices you plug in.